# Python: Selenium browser doesn't fully load while background

Tags: python, selenium, browser

I have an uncommon problem with my selenium chrome driver that never happened to me before.

Here the basic code I'm running:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.fr/")
```

A Chrome browser opens and loads for the asked URL. When I have the browser open at my front application, everything is working fine and the code runs (not showed here)

However, when I put the browser in the background the loading never gets fully done, the page staying white until I put the browser up front.

And this problem is the same  whatever URL I am using.

I assume this change came from an update in the chromedriver since it worked before.

Any solution (besides using headless or firefox)?

Comment: what is the error you get if you leave it in the background?

Comment: I get a NoSuchElementException which is logical since I get a blank page as a response.